# Pronunciation of משנה הלכות

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, jewish-books, pronunciation

Are R' Menashe Klein's volumes of responsa pronounced "Mishna Halachos" or "Mishaneh Halachos"? Can someone provide the grammatical explanation please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Mishne Halachos*, "a summary of *halachos*" like in *Mishne Tora*, "a summary of Torah". The root is shin-nun-he: it's related to *shana*, "repeated".

I've heard that after he allowed certain *eruvin* that R' Moshe Feinstein did not, people jokingly (and with quite a lack of *k'vod hatora*) referred to his books as *M'shane Halachos*, "changer of *halachos*". The root is shin-nun-he, in piel, *shina*, "changed".

Answer (score 5):

It is meant to be Mishneh Halachos. However, some of R. Klein's positions are controversial (not only re eruvin), leading some to dub it Mishaneh Halachos.